# (Swift) Switching between UINavigationController and UITabController nested within Main UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uiview-hierarchy

Through `storyboard`, the app entry point is a separate `UINavigationController` that does some logic on user authentication to first determine whether to push the Home view's embedded `UITabBarController` or present the Sign-In/Sign-Up view's embedded `UINavigationController` - this I was okay with.

The difficulty I have is how to properly make direct transitions between, back-and-forth, the Sign-In/-Sign Up view's embedded `UINavigationController` on sign-in/sign-up and the Home view's embedded `UITabBarController` on sign-out. I believe conflict lies in handling the original `rootviewcontroller` upon entry to push/present the aforementioned views and the "`rootviewcontroller` relationship" the nested `UINavigationController` has within the Sign-In/Sign-Up view.

I don't know how to push/present from the original `rootviewcontroller` for these direct transitions. If someone could help clarify, whether it's using `appdelegate`, etc, it'd be much appreciated!

[Storyboard UI Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw3Er.png)

Comment: arrange it like root view -> SignIn OR SignUp -> Home Screen Tab view
in sign in screen check if logged in immediately push home screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you can handle this, but generally, my go to way is to handle this simply by having one main navigation controller which will keep the entire sign in / main menu array of controllers in it, and simply add or remove the menu from view controllers depending on whether the user is logged in or logged out (show either just [signin] or [signin, mainmenu] as view controllers on navigation controller).

Lastly, depending on what kind of logic the tab bar has, usually I'll embed a navigation controller for each tab bar item.

Take a look at a quick sketch here:
[image: sketch]